# Stopping summation loop as soon as digits after decimal points stop changing

Tags: python

I have a loop that calculates a approximation. The loop should stop as soon as 10 digits after the decimalpoint stop changing. But I just can't get it to stop.
[image: Here is the math function and the error I get]

This is what I tried:

```
summe = 0
i = 0
l = []

while True:
    i = i + 1
    summe = summe + 1/(i**3)
    l.append(format(summe, '.20f'))
    
    if l[i][:14] == l[i+1][:14]:
        break
```

Here is a example of what the first elements of the list looks like:

```
['1.00000000000000000000',
 '1.12500000000000000000',
 '1.16203703703703697947',
 '1.17766203703703697947',
 '1.18566203703703698658',
 '1.19029166666666652574']
```

So it should continue until the first 10 digits after the decimal point stop changing. Also tried it with `i-1` instead of `i+1` in the if statement. So shouldn't it compare the element and the element before with each other? Like `l[3] == l[2]`.

Edit: I just saw it should be [:12] instead of [:14]. But same problem is still there

Comment: Instead of using string-formatting to inspect decimal places, you could inspect them directly with [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). Are you allowed use that?

Comment: Or if you only want to inspect the first 10 dps, better to use `f'{summe:.10f}'`. Using f-strings is more compact than the old string.format. Either way, if you only want to see 10 dps, only output 10dps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
summe = 0
summe_10dps = f'{summe:.10f}'
prev_summe_10dps = '' # anything as long as it's != summe_10dps
i = 0

while summe_10dps != prev_summe_10dps:
    i = i + 1

    prev_summe_10dps = summe_10dps # remember previous sum
    print(f'i={i} {summe_10dps} {prev_summe_10dps}') # check
    summe = summe + 1/(i**3)
    summe_10dps = f'{summe:.10f}'
```

Notes:

- since you only want to inspect the first 10 dps, **only output 10dps**! Instead of outputting unlimited precision then having to string-slice it.
- Using **f-strings `f'{summe:.10f}'` is more compact** than the old `str.format`.
- Inside your loop, keep the previous 10dps string value `prev_summe_10dps`. Then the **loop termination condition is simpler and more efficient, just checking `if summe_10dps == prev_summe_10dps`**
- There's no reason at all to keep a list, you can just directly compare  and termination condition: `while summe_10dps != prev_summe_10dps:` in a while-loop. Or I had done a `while True: ...` with an `if summe_10dps == prev_summe_10dps: break` termination. The former seems slightly better style.
- One slight caveat about implementing the *"first 10 decimal places stop changing"*: beware that **`':.f'` format rounds the unwanted dp's** (rather than truncate), and `'{:.10f}'.format(1.2000000991500)` rounds down to `'1.2000000991'`
- (FYI by the way, the well-known way to get more accuracy, instead sum the series from smallest absolute value to largest, i.e. in reverse order `for i = range(large_value_of_i, 0, step=-1)`. But you're not being asked to do that here.)

Result:

```
...
i=2190 1.2020567989 1.2020567989
i=2191 1.2020567990 1.2020567990
i=2192 1.2020567991 1.2020567991
```

Comment: Thank you! I fully understand now. And thanks for adding the notes, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement requires the list to contain at least two elements. During the first iteration it will only contain one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a shame to use strings for this when you can check it mathematically:

```
summe = 0
i = 1
add = 1.0

while add > 1e-11:
    summe += add
    i += 1
    add = 1/(i**3)
    print(summe)
```